# cummeRbund creating gene sets

Tags: r, vector, bioinformatics

I am using cummeRbund, an R visualization package for Cufflinks high-throughput sequencing data.

I want to create a gene sets to be able to analyse the differentially expressed genes I'm interested in.
This is what the manual suggests:

```
> data(sampleData)
> myGeneIds<-sampleIDs
> myGeneIds

 [1] "XLOC_001363" "XLOC_001297" "XLOC_001339" "XLOC_000132"
 [5] "XLOC_001265" "XLOC_000151" "XLOC_001359" "XLOC_000069"
 [9] "XLOC_000170" "XLOC_000105" "XLOC_001262" "XLOC_001348"
[13] "XLOC_001411" "XLOC_001369" "XLOC_000158" "XLOC_001370"
[17] "XLOC_001263" "XLOC_000115" "XLOC_000089" "XLOC_001240"

> myGenes<-getGenes(cuff,myGeneIds)
```

where sampleIDs is a vector of 'gene_id' or 'gene_short_name' values to identify the genes I wish to select.

I made a normal .txt file with my genes, which looks like this:

```
"XLOC_000012"
"XLOC_000033"
"XLOC_000071"
"XLOC_000080"
"XLOC_000081"
"XLOC_000102"
"XLOC_000105"
"XLOC_000113"
"XLOC_000156"
"XLOC_000191"
"XLOC_000212"
"XLOC_000229"
"XLOC_000230"
"XLOC_000241"
"XLOC_000242"
"XLOC_000293"
"XLOC_000294"
"XLOC_000328"
"XLOC_000356"
"XLOC_000398"
"XLOC_000417"
"XLOC_000434"
"XLOC_000442"
etc...
```

Then, in R, I run these commands:

```
myGeneIds<-read.table("my txt file")
myGenes<-getGenes(cuff,myGeneIds)
> myGenes
CuffGeneSet instance for  1  genes
```

and what I got is just the analysis of the first gene in the txt file. But I have 577 genes in the txt file.

How can I make the vector with my gene_id in order to make cummeRbund work correctly?

Comment: getGenes expects a vector but, if I am not mistaken, read.table will return a data.frame even if your text file only has a column. Try: `myGeneIds<-read.table("my txt file")
myGenes<-getGenes(cuff,myGeneIds[ ,1])`

Comment: I've added my comment as answer in case you want to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getGenes expects a vector but read.table will return a data.frame even if your text file only has a column.This should solve the problem:

```
myGeneIds<-read.table("my txt file") 
myGenes<-getGenes(cuff,myGeneIds[ ,1])
```